# Can I absolutely position an element in the top right corner of a <td> element?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I need the cells to have an element positioned in the upper right corner of each cell.

I've read several other questions asking the same thing but none of them seem to fix the problem.

One solution I have read say to wrap the inside of the cell in a div with relative positioning, but that doesn't work because the div doesn't fill the whole cell, even with height and width set to 100%.

The other solution I have read says to manually set the height of the cells and manually set the height of the div to the same value. This doesn't work for me either because the tables are being dynamically generated and I can't guarantee a certain size for the cells.

Here's some code that illustrates the problem:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="position:relative; height: 100%; background: yellow;">
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <div style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; background: red;">
               absolute
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="position:relative;  height: 100%;  background: yellow;">
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <p>This is some content</p>
            <div style="position:absolute;right:0px; top:0px; background: red;">
               absolute
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what that example looks like http://jsfiddle.net/hqtEQ/

Is there any way I can get the red div into the top right corner of every cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox seems to be the only browser that can't absolutely position something directly in the `td` with `position:relative` (because of the [bug 63895](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895)). Other browsers don't have any problems here. And since version 22, Firefox has supported the latest syntax of Flexbox which a) can emulate table behavior, b) doesn't have problems with `position: relative`. What about using it as a workaround just for Firefox?

```
td {
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
}

:-moz-any-link > html, tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

:-moz-any-link > html, td {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hqtEQ/4/)

Answer (score 5):

The default vertical alignment of a `td` is centered; so, if you're not worried about the other content in the cell just replace

```
<td>
```

with

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
```

(or add a CSS class to this effect) and your layout will work as intended.

See http://jsfiddle.net/hqtEQ/1/

Comment: Is there a way to get the wrapper div to fill the whole cell vertically? This solution works for getting the absolute div into the top corner, but it would be nice to be able to keep the main content centered vertically. This is what it looks like now http://jsfiddle.net/5rvLY/

Comment: That works in Chrome and IE, but not Firefox. According to this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position position: relative is not valid css on <td> elements.

Comment: In which case, your answer may be "no", and you need to look at using div elements instead. If you're using the table for laying content out - rather than for displaying tabular data - this is generally recommended anyway.

Comment: I am displaying actual tabular data. I might have to switch over to divs anyway though...

Comment: @user1850886, it's valid CSS for any element, the spec just doesn't specify the _exact_ effect of offsetting _the cell itself_ by changing its position (e.g. what happens to collapsed borders). The [definition of _containing block_](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) for abs. pos. elements doesn't make any exceptions for `td`s. The behavior of Firefox is [the known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895).