# Conditional cell within a cell in CSS / PHP

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way (probably css based) to have a table cell within a cell in the top-right corner of the mother cell, but only in certain conditions. It's part of a PHP / MySQL structure. 
So, roughly I'm looking for something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr><td>";

if ($something_true) {

$show_cell_like_this;
/*
 ________________
|           |_x_|
|               |
|     blah      |
|_______________|
*/
} else {

$show_cell_differently;
/*
________________
|               |
|               |
|     blah      |
|_______________|  
*/
}

echo "</td></tr></table>";

?>
```

It's the thingy with the 'x' in the top right corner we are talking about. It will be small, either with a button, or with 3 or 4 characters. Obviously, the table will have more cells than just 1 :-). Some cells will contain the 'corner tab', others won't. 
Does anyone have a clue, or even better: a bit of working code?

Comment: why don't you have another cell to diplay `x` if it is true instead of putting inside the cell? or create the `x` with `css display property` or whatever if it is true

Answer (score 0):

If you want a table cell inside of a table cell, inside the first table cell, create a div and set it's display to a table. Inside the div, put your content and set the display to a table cell. I hope that answered your question.

Comment: I guess it's just me being stupid or ignorant, but, umm...? Could you give a coded example of what you are saying? My CSS is rather rusty, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

Run the snippet and I hope that this code will make sense. :)

```css
.table-1 {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px;
}

.table-cell-1 {
  background-color: #0f0;
  display: table-cell;
   padding: 20px;
}

.table-2 {
  display: table;
}

.table-cell-2 {
  background-color: #00f;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table-1">
      <div class="table-cell-1">
        <p>This is a table cell</p>
        <div class="table-2">
          <p class="table-cell-2">This is a table cell in a table cell</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, WG, your code will get me there, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a nice almost-there-solution on this very Stackoverflow:
[Can I absolutely position an element in the top right corner of a <td> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735283/can-i-absolutely-position-an-element-in-the-top-right-corner-of-a-td-element)